# Are eulerAngles reliably to use for local rotation limits?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to allow the camera a certain local rotation (orbit around the player). 
To do that, I calculate a rotation first, then I look at the EulerAngles, and then I state something like this:

```
if ((rotation.eulerAngles.y < 250) && (rotation.eulerAngles.y > 30)) 
{
    //apply rotation
}
```

I would like to ask if using eulerAngles this way / for this purpose is safe or if there is a better method to limit a local rotation?

I'm asking because somebody said that "eulerAngles are ONE expression of a many possible eulerAngles expressions for a certain rotation." (I hope I got that right). That made me wonder if they are reliable.

Thank you!

Comment: Generally speaking, conversion from Quaternion (the stored rotation) to Euler back to Quaternion can do strange things with the Euler representations.  You're better off keeping track of the Euler angles separately in your own class and setting the rotation from them as they change.